Why is system.text.json serializer removing trailing zeros on decimals?
System.Text.Json serializer keeps removing trailing zeros on decimal values.

Are you talking about string values or numeric values? For the latter, this should not matter because "myvalue": 1.00000 and "myvalue": 1 are exactly the same.

I agree but in my case I have to preserve the zeros

From your own answer it seems that this was not even an issue with System.Text.Json but with some beautifier.

Because actual decimal values don't have trailing zeros. A string representation of a decimal might have a trailing zero, but the value itself does not.

@JoelCoehoorn: The value of a System.Decimal can, effectively. (No, they're not actual zeroes internally, but the value "knows" whether or not it's got them.) Unlike System.Single and System.Double, the scale is maintained such that 1.0m and 1.000m have different representations.

System.Text.Json did output trailing zeros, but they were removed by the beautifier.  I'll explain:
You won't find any information on this topic because system.text.json serializer does not remove trailing zeros on decimals.  I spent days on this so hopefully I can save you some time!
The reason I kept thinking trailing zeros were being removed by system.text.json serializer was because I kept taking the output of the serializer, pasting it into Visual Studio Code and beautifying it.  Come to find out, many of the most popular json formatters you get for Visual Studio Code remove the trailing zeros.
As of this writing, the Json Formatter from Clemens Peters resolved this for me.
Even better though, when you serialize, add indented to your options and then you won't have to prettify your json
JsonSerializerOptions options = new(){ WriteIndented = true };

Something like this in the immediate window works nicely (,nq on the end is needed):
System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(targetObject, new JsonSerializerOptions(){ ReferenceHandler = System.Text.Json.Serialization.ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles, WriteIndented = true }),nq


You're implying "System.Text.Json did output trailing zeros, but they were removed by the beautifier".  I think it would be good to explicitly say that in your answer.
